# $2\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}=(2)$ modulo $m$

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $m\mathbb{Z}$ be an ideal of the ring $2\mathbb{Z}.$  Is it true that for any $m>2, 2\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}=(2)$ modulo $m$?  Where $m\mathbb{Z}$ is an ideal of $2\mathbb{Z}$ and $(2):=2\mathbb{Z}$.

I feel that it is yes, using the following examples.
Let $2\mathbb{Z}$ be the ring of even integers.  Consider the ideals $4\mathbb{Z}$ and $8\mathbb{Z}$  of $2\mathbb{Z}$.  From $2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}=\{\bar{0},\bar{2}\}=(2)$ modulo $4$ and $2\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}=\{\bar{0},\bar{2},\bar{4},\bar{6}\}=(2)$ modulo $8$.

Comment: If $m\mathbb{Z}\subseteq 2\mathbb{Z}$, then $m=2n$. As groups, $2\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Writing “$(2)$ modulo $m$” is the same as $2\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, isn't it?

Comment: Is this a question about notation? Because I don't even understand what is meant by "$(2)$ modulo $m$" if not.

Comment: It is impossible to guess why you might think they are different when you have not defined what you think they are in the first place.  The former notation seems to be completely standard, and I don't recognize the latter notation as anything common.  Typically "mod" or "modulo" is used in the context of writing an element, not the set of elements.

Comment: I meant $2\mathbb{Z}$ by writing $(2)$.  So by $(2)$ modulo $m$ I mean the element of $2\mathbb{Z}$ up to modulo $m$.